# Calling a JApplet with HTML file, opening in Firefox

Tags: java, html, firefox, applet

I wrote a Java GUI that I recently tried converting into a JApplet via [these instructions](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_applet_basics.htm) (Application conversion to Applets) so that I could embed it in a website. The transition from GUI to Applet seemed to work, since running the program in Eclipse is fully functional - now it just opens in an Applet viewer instead of a JFrame. However, getting the JApplet to show up in my web browser, has been tougher.

Lets call my Eclipse workspace 'ws1'. It is structured as follows:

- Current_Java_Project

  - src

    - package

      - MainProgram.java
      - OtherClasses.java

A couple of notes to be thorough:

1. There are 5 total classes in package, MainProgram defines the class that extends JApplet
2. The package is not the default package, there is no default package. There's only one package though (not sure if that matters)

Then I have the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Applet Test</title>
<hr>
    <applet code="MainProgram.class" width="480" height="320"></applet>
<hr>
</html>
```

I wasn't sure where to stick this html file. First I put it in the local workspace location in the 'bin' folder (where it can find the .class files). When I do this, I get an Application Error alert window titled "NoClassDefFoundError" and the message "MainProgram (wrong name: package/MainProgram" with no other details. Copying the .java files from the workspace to another location, compiling .class files with javac via command line, and then running the same html file from that other location also doesn't work, giving me the same error.

I assume there is something wrong with the way I am calling for the applet in my HTML, or something wrong with how my files are arranged, since the Applet runs just fine from Eclipse. If anyone thinks it might be something in the JApplet code itself, please let me know.

Additional Notes:

1. I am testing this html in Firefox, and have edited my Java System Preferences so that both paths I have tried this on (the workspace path and the alternate path, both with the HTML and .class files) are on the Java Exception Site List (so that I could test this out without the hardships of JApplet permissions). I don't know if that could be a problem.
2. I'm using the most recent version of JRE, which I believe is Java 7, update 65.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the html in the **Current_Java_Project** directory and use `codebase` to point to the location of the class files.

Try something like:

```
  <applet code="MainProgram.class" codebase="bin/"width="480" height="320"></applet>
```

Where **bin** is the directory under **Current_Java_Project** containing `MainProgram.class`

Answer (score 0):

The `<applet>` tag is not supported in HTML5. Use `<embed>` or `<object>` instead. `<object classid="MyApplet.class" codebase="/path/to/classes"></object>`